# Best way to maximize current income from stock market as a low income person

Tags: stocks, 401k, index-fund, starting-out-investing, checking-account

Due to some health problems it is quite difficult for me to work full time. I get my income from odd jobs and on-line surveys. I was wondering what the best way to maximize some of that income. Whether its in the stock market or via a 401k to try and save for the future. I have never made enough money to file taxes but it wouldn't be to hard for me to try and add 10 dollars a week or so to some high yield account. I really want to avoid my savings account as it is to easy to spend any money I put in there.

Thanks, let me know if y'all need more information.

Comment: I would try invest in some type of skill training or knowledge that you can increase you earnings above $10,000 a year that works around/with your health problems.  Also, except for a IRA, brokerage accounts are almost as liquid as savings accounts so if you don't have discipline not to spend your savings you won't have it not to spend the money in a brokerage account.  Just some suggestions and good luck.

Comment: Ever met someone who got rich using a 401k?  Sounds like you may have some time on your hand so I would suggest getting a financial eduction and rely on your education rather than on strangers on the inter webs.  That being said, I think you should educate yourself in real estate investing.  You can do it with little money and a lot of creativity.  It is a hard asset and cash flows every month should you do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, since you are "self-employed", you were required to file a tax return and pay self-employment tax, i.e. pay into the social security system, both as worker and employee.

This would also enable you to start a Solo 401(k), and fund that retirement account.

Answer (score -3):

A 401-K is something you get through an employer. I recommend getting a self-directed IRA.

You can open an IRA with Scottrade with $500 The money you put into an IRA is tax deferred, meaning that you do not have to pay taxes on profits. It may also lower your tax liability.

Scottrade has a feature to automatically reinvest any dividends from the securities you own. This feature allows you to avoid commissions on those automatic purchases.

Don't try to time the market. Pick a good ETF (exchange traded fund) that pays dividends. It will give you diversification.

Avoid the urge to buy and sell constantly. This only gives commissions to the broker.

Comment: tax deferred means that you pay taxes on profits. You are right that you don't pay taxes on profits with (some) IRAs, but that's because it's funded with post-tax money, not tax deferred.